# How to store 10 most recent objects in a Firebase?

Tags: firebase

I want a Firebase to hold the last 10 most recently added objects, but no more. I'll use a web server log as an example.

Say I have a program watching a web server log. Every time a new entry is made in the log, I want my Firebase to get the IP address from that entry. But I only need the Firebase to store the last 10 IP addresses sent, not every one it ever received.

I can imagine doing this by setting up 10 objects in Firebase, say:

```
app/slot0
app/slot1
app/slot2
app/slot3
etc
```

Then PATCH slot0 to add the IP and, when done, update the slot tracker:

`currentSlot++`

And when currentSlot gets to 10 it wraps around and points to 0

`if(currentSlot > numSlots) currentSlot = 0;`

So that it's basically a list of 10 objects and I'm manually keeping track of which slot is the next one. This way I don't need to store an infinite number of items, but only the last 10. And clients listening to all of these slots will get updates every time one changes.

My question is whether this is an optimal way of doing this? I can't help thinking there is a more efficient way.

Comment: Show your work. Can't even tell what language we're working in here.

Answer (score 2):

There's 100 different ways to do this but here's a thought:

Assume that an app stores 10 IP's in an array (0-9) and the IP at index 0 is the latest IP connection.

When a new connection is made, the IP at index 9 is removed from he array and the IPs at 0-8 have their indexes incremented (IP at index 0 moves to index 1, IP at index 1 moved to index 2 etc).

Then the newest IP is inserted at item 0. The array data is written to Firebase.

Depending on your platform, this is easy as inserting an IP into the array at index 0 and removing index 10, then writing to firebase.

However, try to avoid writing arrays into Firebase. There are much better ways to do this - a node with IP and a timestamp would work well.

```
connection_events
   connection_id_0123
      ip: 192.168.1.1
      timestamp: 20151107133000
   connection_id_4566
      ip: 198.168.1.123
      timestamp: 20151107093000
```

The connection_id's are generated by childByAutoId or push so they are 'random' but you always have the timestamp to order by.

Another thought using the above structure is to Firebase query for the oldest one and remove that node, then add the newest one. This would work since ordering is controlled by the timestamp.

Comment: Querying for the oldest is the best choice here; numeric ids are problematic as you've alluded. But both of these solutions assume there won't be concurrent edits; things get fairly complicated when that comes into play.

Comment: @Kato the connection_id_0123 and connection_id_4566 indicated in my answer are actually childByAutoId or push generated random node id's. I should have stated that in my answer. Also, I assumed it was a single program performing these changes within Firebase. If there are concurrent sessions going on this data, that should be taken into consideration as that get's more tricky for sure.